# load several classes. How to use Restler3 AutoLoader?

Tags: autoloader, restler

**FIRST :**
Thank you for this great "Restler" !

**MY CONTEXT :** 
I use Restler 3 to build my own API and return the total score of my users (on games).
Example : "www.mysite.com/api/score/12345" => Return the total score (json object) of user id "12345"

But, to get the total score (from the different games), i need to use my own library (called "scorers") and its classes :
- vendor/damGames/scorers/scoreGameA.class.php
- vendor/damGames/scorers/scoreGameB.class.php
- vendor/damGames/scorers/scoreGameC.class.php
- etc...

**MY QUESTION IS :**
To load the classes of my library, should i use the "Luracast\Restler\AutoLoader" ? I don't understand how... Else, how can i do ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

**The only solution I found :**

In the first lines of my Restler class called "*Score*", I put :

```
use Luracast\Restler\RestException;
use damGames\scorers\scoreGameA;
use damGames\scorers\scoreGameB;
use damGames\scorers\scoreGameC;
...
```

It's a good way to do ? Have you something better ?